# algebraic connectivity greater than $1$

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

**Some Background**

The *algebraic connectivity* of a graph $G$ is defined as the second smallest Laplacian eigenvalue of the graph and is denoted by $a(G)$.

It is known that $a(G)\le1$ if $G$ is a tree and in particular, when the tree is a star then equality holds. 
Further, if $G$ is a complete graph, then $a(G)=n$ where $n$ is the number of vertices of $G$.

**My Question**

Let $n-1< k<~ ^n\!C_2-n$. Then what is the maximum value of $k$ for which we can guarantee that if $G$ is a connected graph on $n$ vertices and $k$ edges, then $$a(G)<1?$$

Answer (score 0):

1. $a$ should only increase if you take the star graph and add edges between "exterior" vertices, so that means the maximum of $a$ over graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges is at least $1$ if $k \geq n-1$. (I'm not sure how to rigorously prove this, though I'm pretty confident that it is true.)
2. $a$ is necessarily $0$ if the graph is disconnected. This is guaranteed if $k<n-1$.

I think to make your question interesting you need some topological restrictions.

Comment: I have edited it to only connected graphs.

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e You miss the point: if $k \geq n-1$ then the maximum value of $a$ over all such graphs is at least $1$ because you can always add edges to the star graph. If $k<n-1$ then the graph is already disconnected and so the problem is of course trivial (the maximum is exactly $0$). Thus all in all the whole problem is somewhat trivial (the only difficulty is to show that $a$ is monotone with respect to the relation of inclusion of edge sets).